# Why do we install dependencies during Docker's final "CMD" command, in development?

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, npm

I'm working through a book about bootstrapping microservices, and the author provides the following dockerfile, which is meant to be used in development.**

```
FROM node:12.18.1-alpine
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package*.json .
CMD npm config set cache-min 999999 && \
   npm install && \
   npm run start:dev
```

The `CMD` command here is obviously somewhat unusual. The rationale provided is as follows: By doing the `npm install` when the container starts, we can "make use of npm caching so it's much faster to install at container startup than if we installed it during the build process."

What is going on behind the scenes here with the `CMD` command? How is this different from having a `RUN` command that installs the dependencies prior to the `CMD` command? And relatedly, why do we need to set a `cache-min` policy?

**The source files are not copied over here because they are included in a mounted volume.

EDIT: Here is the docker compose file as well

```
version: '3'
services:
  history:
    image: history
    build:
      context: ./history
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-dev
    container_name: history
    volumes:
      - /tmp/history/npm-cache:/root/.npm:z
      - ./history/src:/usr/src/app/src/:z
    ports:
      - '4002:80'
    environment:
      - PORT=80
      - NODE_ENV=development
    restart: 'no'

    ...
```

Comment: See [Docker RUN vs CMD vs ENTRYPOINT](https://goinbigdata.com/docker-run-vs-cmd-vs-entrypoint/). In the example you provide, I suspect at least some of that should be launched as `RUN`.

Comment: If all of the code is on the host, and you'll re-run `npm install` on every execution, I'm not sure what you'd gain from inserting Docker into this sequence; it seems exactly like using a host Node environment, except that it requires extra files and administrator-level permissions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you develop, you often change the packages that are included in the project. By doing it this way, you don't need to build a new image when you do that. You can just stop and start the container and it'll install the new packages.

I am a little surprised by the copying of package*.json though. I'd assume that that would be passed into the image using a volume like you say the source code is. It can still be done like that and maybe it is. We'd need to see your `docker run` command do know if it is.

Comment: "By doing it this way, you don't need to build a new image when you do that. You can just stop and start the container and it'll install the new packages." – That's much clearer, thank you! I'm adding the docker-compose file to my question if you are interested.

Comment: What's the reason that you're surprised that the package*.json isn't moved over as a mounted volume as well? Wouldn't copying it over and including it as a mounted file accomplish the same thing?

Comment: I was thinking that the volume you map into the container will hide the package*.json file(s) that were copied into the container when you build it. If you map your volume to /usr/src/app, then you can no longer access the package.json file from the image. You probably have the package file in your source directory on the host machine as well, so it doesn't matter that much. But I think you can remove the COPY statement from the Dockerfile and it'll still work.